# Detect when a NSStatusItem has been removed via drag and drop

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

One can set a `NSStatusItem's` `behaviour` property to `removalAllowed` (`NSStatusItemBehaviorRemovalAllowed`)
Then a user can remove the item from the status bar using drag and drop.

[image: removing the WiFi status item from the status bar]

*Example: removing the WiFi status item from the status bar*

However, I am unable to detect when the statusbar is being removed so I can remember it and not show it the next time the user starts the app. There is no delegate or notification and the `statusBar` property is *readonly* so I can't override the setter.

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitembehavior/nsstatusitembehaviorremovalallowed?language=objc) for `NSStatusItemBehaviorRemovalAllowed` says:

> Upon removal, the item’s visible property changes to NO. This change is observable using key-value observation.

So you could add a KVO observer for that property, and if it changes to `NO` (and assuming you didn't set it to `NO`), don't show your status bar item on future launches.

---

That said, in testing this out: the system handles this for you fairly well. When you create your status bar item, don't set the `visible` property, and set an [autosaveName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem/1644022-autosavename?language=objc). If the user removes your item from the status bar, the system writes that to the app's preferences in ~/Library/Preferences, and your status bar item won't be visible on future launches.

To restore the visibility, manually set the `visible` property to `YES`.

Comment: Since the question is for Swift, that would be `true` or `false` instead of `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: I totally missed that in the documentation. Thanks! :)